# How to flatten JSON using Gson

Tags: java, json, gson

I need to flatten a JSON strings(nested) using Gson ,

Given:

```json
{
   "name": "Terry",
   "addr": {
       "city": "NY",
       "postCode": 123
   },
   "friends": ["John", "Paul"],
   "nestedObject": { "a": { "b": { "c": {"d": "nested property" } } } }
}
```

Expected:

```json
{
  "name" :"Terry",
  "addr.city": "NY",
  "addr.postCode" : 123,
  "friends.0": "John",
  "friends.1":  "Paul",
  "nestedObject.a.b.c.d": "nested property"
}
```

or

```json
{
  "name" :"Terry",
  "addr.city": "NY",
  "addr.postCode" : 123,
  "friends[0]": "John"
  "friends[1]": "Paul"
  "nestedObject.a.b.c.d": "nested property"
}
```

Really new to Java and need guidance how to build it up ,

My starting point :

1.Parse the Json using JsonParser as TreeModel
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/gson/gson_tree_model.htm
just found that JsonParser is deprecated :(

https://javadoc.io/doc/com.google.code.gson/gson/latest/com.google.gson/com/google/gson/JsonParser.html

is there alternative ?

2.Recursive function to loop through the Json elements and check
if element is list/dict - case yes , recursive call with all child ,
case else - append current key and val to some map

real pseudo code:

```
public class Test{

    public static void main(String[] args) {


        String jsonString = "{\"brand\" : \"Toyota\", \"doors\" : 5}";

        JsonObject jsonObject = JsonParser.parseString(jsonString).getAsJsonObject();


// Iterate through main key and call FlatJson for each one
// append result to a map 
//print result
```

FlatJson - for given element ,
extract all child key

```
    public String FlatJson(  JsonElement jsonElement) {

        

        // If input is an array, iterate through each element
        if (jsonElement.isJsonArray()) {
            for (JsonElement jsonElement1 : jsonElement.getAsJsonArray()) {
                // Extract Key Value and return 
                    
                
            }
        } else {

            // If input is object, iterate through the keys
            if (jsonElement.isJsonObject()) {
                Set<Map.Entry<String, JsonElement>> entrySet = jsonElement
                        .getAsJsonObject().entrySet();
                for (Map.Entry<String, JsonElement> entry : entrySet) {
                    // Extract Key Value and return 
                    }

                }
            }

            // If input is element, check whether it corresponds to the key
            else {
                    // return sonElement.toString() (as
                }
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: It can be done pretty easy using Gson itself. What have you tried already? _I use Gson for parsing_ -- the code please?

Comment: Thanks fluffy , glad to understand it possible to flat json using Gson , i use Gson for basic json object extract but not sure where to start to flat json ,hopefully some1 willing to share the approach

Comment: Take a look at `JsonReader` (especially it's `getPath()` and `.next...()` methods), `JsonWriter`, and use stacked approach or recursion (for example). This is where you could start and basically implement it all.

Comment: I edit my post with some pseudo code , would really appreciate if some1 can share some code i could start with

Comment: Please re-read my comment above: it has sufficient amount of hints to accomplish your target. Note that you don't need to deserialize it to `JsonElement`-trees as it consumes more memory. The suggestion I'm suggesting can use streamed approach. Really, `JsonReader` and `JsonWriter` are your only friends here. Good luck!